# SVG mask not resizing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, svg

When resizing a SVG in Chrome the mask inside it doesn't resize with it. So in the example below the image resizes correctly with correct slicing but the mask is stuck in the original position.

In e.g. Safari the mask resizes correctly.

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="m">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g)" />
    </mask>
    <linearGradient id="g" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0.3" stop-opacity="0.0" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="1.0" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <image mask="url(#m)" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://unsplash.it/5092/3395?image=1062" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
</svg>
```

You can play around with it in this pen: 
https://codepen.io/larsenwork/pen/9dc4bb319109e719728a01bac9bba0d4

Answer (score 0):

Update css part

```
svg { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; /* Use height in vh */
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #bada55;
  height: 90vh;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <mask id="m">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff" />
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g)" />
    </mask>
    <linearGradient id="g" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0.3" stop-opacity="0.0" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="1.0" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <image mask="url(#m)" width="100%" height="100%" xlink:href="https://unsplash.it/5092/3395?image=1062" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"></image>
</svg>
```